# django - duplicate model with cascade inheritance

Tags: django, inheritance

I have a three-level model inheritance:

```
class Node(models.Model):
    # all node fields are here

class QuestionNode(Node):
    # all user-input-related fields are here

class RequestContactNode(QuestionNode):
    # all fields specific for this request type are here
```

now, I can duplicate `QuestionNode` object like so:

```
>>> from nodes.models import QuestionNode, RequestContactNode
>>> qnode = QuestionNode.objects.create(name='q', position=1)
>>> print(qnode.pk)
1240
>>> qnode.pk, qnode.id = None, None
>>> qnode.save()
>>> print(qnode.pk)
1241
```

But this doesn't work with `RequestContactNode`, which is next level of inheritance:

```
>>> rcnode = RequestContactNode.objects.create(name='q', position=1,
...                                            request_button_text='Share my number')
>>> print(rcnode.pk)
1242
>>> rcnode.pk, rcnode.id = None, None
>>> rcnode.save()
>>> print(rcnode.pk)
1242
```

Why is that and is there a workaround for it?

Comment: what does your class Meta look like

Comment: @e4c5 it only defines 2 attributes: `verbose_name` and `verbose_name_plural`, for each of three classes: `Node`, `QuestionNode` and `RequestContactNode`. Nothing else.